# How to detect camera orientation javascript webrtc

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, browser, webrtc

How can I use image processing method when computer's camera has for example 640x480 resolution and phone's one 480x640

Answer (score -1):

if you just want the dimensions of the video, the videoWidth and videoHeight properties of the HTML video element allow querying that.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/ shows an example including how to draw the current video content onto a canvas element.